# How to query Case-insensitive data in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-orm, case-insensitive

How can I query/filter in Django and ignore the cases of my query-string?

I've got something like and like to ignore the case of `my_parameter`:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(name=my_parameter)
```

Answer (score 586, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(name__iexact=my_parameter)
```

There is even a way to use it for substring search:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(name__icontains=my_parameter)
```

There's a [link to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: Would you please explain what "substring search" means?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari You search inside a string, for example you search for "beer" and you get the matches "beer" and "beers".

Comment: And for example a match with "there is beer in my stomach".

Comment: doc for iexact: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact

Comment: It is sql `like`

Comment: Well done sir, this has given me like 3 hours of trouble :)