# How to make case insensitive queries with Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have an `member` model with contains an `email` field. I recently realized that if a part of the email is capitalized, it won't show up in Django queries if I try to filter by the email (multiple member objects have the same email, but it may not be capitalized). I could have just made all emails lower-case when entering them into the database, but it's too late for that now (as the website is already launched). So how do I check who has a certain email, without being case sensitive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Model - Case-insensitive Query / Filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743207/django-model-case-insensitive-query-filtering)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just use [iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
User.objects.filter(email__iexact='email@email.com')
```

> Case-insensitive exact match. If the value provided for comparison is None, it will be interpreted as an SQL NULL (see isnull for more details).

Answer (score 9):

```
Member.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
```