# lower() in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

This is my query

`` SELECT * FROM `music` where lower(music.name) = "hello" ``

How can I send this query with django

I tried this but it didn't add lower in the query

```
>>> Music.objects.filter(name__iexact="hello")
(0.144) SELECT `music`.`id`, `music`.`name`, `music`.`artist`, `music`.`image`, `music`.`duration`, `music`.`release_date`, `music`.`is_persian` FROM `music` WHERE `music`.`name` LIKE 'hello' LIMIT 21; args=('hello',)
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Any reason it should? `LIKE 'hello'` is sufficient to do case insensitive matching for your DB backend.

Comment: What DB backend are you using? As @JonClements mentioned, it likely matches case insensitive by default.

Comment: [Case-insensitive Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743207/django-model-case-insensitive-query-filtering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Lower` [database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#lower) as below.

```
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Lower
>>> lower_name_music = Music.objects.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
>>> lower_name_music.filter(lower_name__iexact="hello")
```

- First statement is to import the database function.
- Second statement is to add calculated column named `lower_name` using
  Lower function on `name` column. At this time database is not yet been
  queried.
- Third statement is to filter using the calculated column. As this
  statement prints out result, a query is actually executed against
  database.