# Django-case insensitive string comparison in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

How to do case insensitive string comparison?

In my case , i need to add a class **menu_active** when topic.title equals page.slug. but,now

- topic.title= home
- page.slug = Home

so my condition fails

nav_bar.html

```
{% for topic in landing_pages %}
     <li role="presentation">
<a class="{% if topic.title == page.slug %}menu_active{% endif %}" href="/{{topic.slug}}/">{{topic.title}}</a>
     </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Model - Case-insensitive Query / Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743207/django-model-case-insensitive-query-filtering)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the strings through the built-in template tag lower/upper and then compare.

```
<a class="{% if topic.title|lower == page.slug|lower %}menu_active{% endif %}
```