# How to perform model.objects.get(**kwargs) with case insensitive

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to get an instance of one of my Django models by using dictionary in an insensitive case way. For the moment I'm using:

my_model.objects.get(**dictionary)

But I don't get the instance if there is a difference of lower / upper case between what there is in my dictionary and the fields of the instance.

Do you think there is a clean way to perform this operation ?

Comment: No, in fact Django does not know *how* you call it. If you call `some_function(**some_dict)`, Python will simply replace that with `some_function(key1=val1, key2=val2)`, etc. This is just argument unpacking.

Comment: Thanks to you and this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743207/django-model-case-insensitive-query-filtering, I found how to do it.I just have to rename the keys of my dictionary from 'key' to 'key__iexact' and it's working !

Answer (score 4):

Django takes the `WHERE` filter to load the object entirely from the keys of the dictionary you provide. It is up to you to provide [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro); you can use the [`iexact` field lookup type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-iexact), but you do need to use this on *textual* fields.

So if you wanted to match a specific string field, case insensitively, add `__iexact` to the key in `dictionary`; e.g. `{'foo': 'bar'}` becomes `{'foo__iexact': 'bar'}`.