# Why django filter is not working for not case sensitive search

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to fetch the data from django models,

where as

```
TaskBlockers.objects.filter(task__project=1,task__team='Backend')
```

gives queryset with 3 objects

```
TaskBlockers.objects.filter(task__project=1,task__team='backend')
```

gives empty queryset.

it was supposed to return same for both the queries isn't it? if now why is this happening and how  can I rectify it for both type of input.

here are my models.

```
class TaskBlockers(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTask,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='task_id_related')
    blocker = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    task_desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query Case-insensitive data in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743207/how-to-query-case-insensitive-data-in-django-orm)

Comment: NO I know we can use __iexact for case sensitive searches, what I wanted to know if I was trying to search for 'Backend' I was getting output, but for 'backend' it was null. why is that happening?

Comment: `__iexact` is used for case **insensitive** (not sensitive) searches. When you don't provide the lookup the `__exact` lookup is used which is case sensitive. Why would you get the same result for both queries given that you are using an `exact` lookup and both are different values?

Answer (score 0):

#### try below query lookups...

```
data = Demo.objects.filter(name__iexact='Rakesh') # required string exact match, but not required case-sensitive. 
data = Demo.objects.filter(name__exact='rakesh') # required string exact match, but not required case-sensitive.
```